# Connection failure to a JMS remote client

Tags: client, jms, jms-topic

I am trying to send message to a JMS queue, however I get this error:

```
    13:48:00,686 WARN  [SimpleConnectionManager] A problem has been detected with the connection 
    to remote client 5c4o15e-ymtiah-hy5hsfkr-1-hy5hsg3i-4, jmsClientID=b-k8gsh5yh-1-rkfsh5yh-
    haitmy-e51o4c5. It is possible the client has exited without closing its connection(s) or the 
    network has failed. All associated connection resources will be cleaned up.
```

One of the suggestions on the we o how to fix this was to change the periodicity of client pings to:

```
    <attribute name="clientLeasePeriod" isParam="true">20000</attribute>
    <attribute name="validatorPingPeriod" isParam="true">20000</attribute>
    <attribute name="validatorPingTimeout" isParam="true">10000</attribute>
```

But it still didn't help. 
Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this or what might cause the connection failure to a client?

Comment: I am afraid you need to provide a lot more information than this. What JMS provider are you using? How do you try to connect (code)? Is the JMS Server run by you or not?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have closed the TopicSession and TopicConnection object in your producer, or in your case QueueConnection and QueueSession objects.